# Typescript: User the correct parameters: TS2345: Argument of type 'T' is not assignable to parameter of type 'new () => any'.

Tags: typescript, methods

I'm using Typescript 2 and trying to write a universal parser-method for database objects. I'm using [TypedJSON](https://github.com/JohnWeisz/TypedJSON) and can't get the parameters in the correct way. My code:

```
private static parseToInstance<T>(dbObject: string, model: T): T {
    try {
        console.log("parseToInstance()")
        let a = TypedJSON.stringify(dbObject);
        return TypedJSON.parse(a, new model, "whatever"
    } catch (err) {
        throw new ParseException(err);
    }
}
```

The Method expects something like:

```
/**
* Converts a JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) string into an instance of the provided class.
* @param text A valid JSON string.
* @param type A class from which an instance is created using the provided JSON string.
* @param settings Per-use serializer settings. Unspecified keys are assigned from global config.
*/
parse<T>(text: string, type: {new (): T;}, settings?: SerializerSettings): T;
```

My code has the following error:

```
Error:(125, 30) TS2345:Argument of type 'T' is not assignable to parameter of type 'new () => {}'.
```

I tried numerous things but can't get it right. Maybe someone can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the `{new (): T;}` type annotation that indicates a constructor.

To support this, you need to make a couple of changes in your `parseToInstance` function. First, rather than `model: T` (nice pun) you need to annotate the type as `{new():T}` to indicate it's definitely a constructor. Unlike some other popular languages TS generics won't always describe classes so this needs to be specified. Second, you shouldn't be calling `new` on model before you pass it in. That would kind of undo the point of passing a constructor function.

```
private static parseToInstance<T>(dbObject: string, model: {new():T}): T {
    try {
        console.log("parseToInstance()")
        let a = TypedJSON.stringify(dbObject);
        return TypedJSON.parse(a, model, "whatever");
    } catch (err) {
        throw new ParseException(err);
    }
}
```

p.s. you dropped a closing paren on parse, I added it back.

Answer (score 1):

It should probably be something like:

```
private static parseToInstance<T>(dbObject: string, model: { new(): T }): T {
    ...
    return TypedJSON.parse(a, model, "whatever");
}
```

Two changes:

1. It's `{ new(): T }` instead of just `T`
2. You shouldn't pass `new model`, just the `model`